# RecyclerView doesn't stay modified after changes

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm having an issue when deleting or adding items to a RecyclerView element, the problem is not when adding or deleting itself, so I explain the situation.

I have a recycler and a button to add elements to it, if the user press a view, it shows a dialog that contains a delete button and some more stuff. I can add and/or delete items on recycler view, and the view updates ok, using `notifyDataSetChanged()`, but when I press **back button**(only by doing this, not any other way) the view reappears again (in case of deletion) or disappear( if I did an adding) setting the recycler the way it was before changes, and I don't want this behavior, because of the delete and add method I created don't just add/delete the view, but associated data in a database too, so If I press the view after deletion the app crash because there are not such data anymore, but the view exists still.

All this content is inside a fragment accessible by a Navigation Drawer, if I navigate other fragment and return to this one again the back press do not affect the recycler anymore, and all those "ghosts" views desapear becouse the data is reloaded from database.
I need a som help for avoiding this, I know undo deletion can be done, but I don want to, I just want to delete data.

**UPDATE:** This is exactly what happens, the vanishing/reappearing of the items in the recycler View is caused by a back button pressed

This one shows the vanishing after adding
[image: This one shows the vanishing after adding]

This one shows the reappearing after deleting
[image: This one shows the reappearing after deleting]

**UPDATE 2:** I've solved the problem by overriding the onBackPressed method using [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-custom-back) documentation from google, when back pressed what I do is to navigate to first fragment in the navigation, this is not what I wanted but solved the problem temporarily (as a patch), I'm still looking for answer.

**UPDATE 3:** Posted my own answer with the fix of all this problem, not using onBackPressed, it worked fine, and I realize some curious behavior

Comment: what do you do when back button pressed?

Comment: This method it's not defined by me, I don't even know if there is such method on fragments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you may notice my app has a navigation drawer, when trying to fix the problem by overridig the onBackPressed() in fragment, I tried to get back to the first fragment in my navigation drawer, when doing so I realize an error that I had not realized before:

> NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected(menuItem,navController);

This line was duplicated in the NavigationItemSelectedListener:

```
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull final MenuItem menuItem) {
                int id=menuItem.getItemId();
                //this line indicates the action of changing fragment using navController reference
                NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected(menuItem,navController);
                if (id==R.id.nav_cuanto){
                    Handler mHandler = new Handler();
                    mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);}
                    },300);
                }
                if(id==R.id.nav_reportes){
//                    NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected(menuItem,navController);  -> this line caused the hole problem
                    Handler mHandler = new Handler();
                    mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);}
                    },300);
                }
                if(id==R.id.nav_about){
                    Handler mHandler = new Handler();
                    mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                        }
                    },300);
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
```

I deleted the line and everything worked just fine, as expected, this particular method creates a new instance of the fragment you are trying to navigate to, but the problem is that when you try to navigate to the fragment you already are in, it creates a new instance a navigate to it, and this new instance is on the over the old one, so when back pressed the app do not return to previous view, but to the same fragment with the old view (out of date, of couse), I couldn't imagine this behavior, this is highly not imaginable, and it's not in the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/ui/NavigationUI.html#onNavDestinationSelected(android.view.MenuItem,%20androidx.navigation.NavController)) so I almost die trying to understand. So **WARNING:** if someone is trying to use

> NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected(menuItem,navController);

do not use it more than once in the same call, if so you will need to press back twice in best case scenario :-(

Answer (score 0):

your lists are out of sync. you have 2 lists, one that holds a reference for you collection of objects that are  passed to the recycler, the other one is within the recycler to iterate over and draw your view holders.

I suggest once you delete|add sth, beside DB, do it to the outer list (one outside recycler) and pass the list as a whole to the recycler. this way you will ensure that the recycler's list is always up-to-date.

this is not the best solution out there, other possible solutions might include an RX Supported Db with no intermediate calls to invoke the recycler.

Comment: Already did this, but this is not what it's going on, the recycler does update ok, but when I **press the back button**,  it returns to the previous view, I actually never coded this part at all, it might be some default behavior or something,  but I don'n know how to disable it, if so